# Block Producer Node no pending Tx's

Tags: stake-pool

Please excuse the noob-ic question:

My block producer node shows 0 Total Tx and 0 Pending Tx on gLiveView:

[image: Core Node]

However, my two relay nodes have non-zero total and pending tx values, and seem to only be going up. Here is a screenshot of one:

[image: Relay Node]

The BP is connected to the two relays, and the two relays are connected to each other as well as other relays. Is this going to be a problem for block production or is this expected/normal?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Possible solutions:**

**First:** In your mainnet-config.json file, set "TraceMemPool": true

Then restart the node.

[image: Block Producer mainnet-config.json]

**Second:** Another issue is that there are no peers in. You need to add your block producer to the topology of the relay node(s).

[image: Incoming/Outgoing Peer Topology]

**Update:** OP mentioned the issue being with the UFW configuration. For reference, here is an image of how I have my UFW setup on my stake pool. This is 4 Relay nodes, 1 Block Producer node and 1 Stand-By Block Producer node setup.

[image: SNOWY Stake pool UFW configuration]

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! it made me realize this whole time I was just being a dingus and my UFW rules were a wee bit off. Just fixed it and it works fine.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help!

Comment: Wow thanks for sharing your UFW setup! You made these yourself?.. Giving me fuel to step my game up as an SPO!